# Is it safe to delete these files?

Tags: macos, mac, unix

I came across these files in my home directory:

- .bash_history
- .bash_sessions (directory)
- .lesshst

and I cant help my OCD-ness and I want to remove them, is it safe?

Comment: You can choose not to show hidden system files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These files should be minuscule in size, and are actually handy to have. Not to mention they will reappear, unless you reconfigure them not to do so.

**.lesshst**

> Name  of  the  history file used to remember search commands and
>                 shell commands between invocations of less.  **If set  to  "-",  a
>                 history  file  is  not used.**  The default is "$HOME/.lesshst" on
>                 Unix systems, "$HOME/_lesshst" on DOS and  Windows  systems,  or
>                 "$HOME/lesshst.ini" or "$INIT/lesshst.ini" on OS/2 systems.

**.bash_history**

> When the -o history option to the set builtin is enabled, the shell
>          provides access to the command history, the list of commands
>          previously typed.

**.bash_sessions (directory)**

> From [Reddit about El Capitan changes](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/): A new folder (`~/.bash_sessions/`) is used to store `HISTFILE`'s and `.session` files that are unique to sessions. If `$BASH_SESSION` or `$TERM_SESSION_ID` is set upon launching the shell (i.e. if Terminal is resuming from a saved state), the associated `HISTFILE` is merged into the current one, and the `.session` file is ran. Session saving is facilitated by means of an `EXIT` trap being set for a function `bash_update_session_state`.

Answer (score 7):

Your system will still work. However they will just come back, why do you want to remove them? They are harmless and shouldn't be taking up space on the disk.